# Stop IntelliJ from deleting my changelist when committing

Tags: intellij-idea, commit, changelist

Suppose I have some files in a changelist named "Files that are ready for commit because I have updated their unit tests".

When I then commit the files in that changelist, (the files are committed just fine but) the changelist itself disappears. I then re-create the changelist for my following work.

I'm sure I managed to set a check mark or otherhow respond "yes, please delete my changelist when I commit all its files". How do I reverse this setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Version Control > Confirmation:

[image: settings]

"When empty changelist becomes inactive" is the setting you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. Hum, that setting is already set to "do not remove", I'll change it to "show options" and try this again.